# Get data from dropdown list and display it in the form of table

Tags: django

I'm new in Django. Here, I want to get data from drop down list, when click on save button, the data should display in the form of table.
Please help me out to solve this. Please.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.upload,name='upload'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def upload(request):
    machines = Machine.objects.all()
    return render(request,'usermaster/upload.html',{'machines':machines})
```

**models.py:**

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    operation_no = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.machine_name
```

**upload.html:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select>
        <option>Select Machine Name</option>
        {% for machine in machines %}
        <option>{{ machine.machine_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <select>
        <option>Select Operation Number</option>
        {% for machine in machines %}
        <option>{{ machine.operation_no }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<tr>
    <td>{{machine.machine_name}}</td>
    <td>{{machine.operation_no}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `views.py`:

```
def save_machine(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      machine_name = request.POST.get('machine_name','')
      operation_no = request.POST.get('operation_no','')
      choiced_machine = Machine.objects.get(machine_name=machine_name, operation_no=operation_no)
      machines = Machine.objects.all()
      return render(request,'usermaster/upload.html',{'machines':machines,'choiced_machine':choiced_machine})
```

In your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('save',views.save_machine,name='save_machine'),
#your other url paths
]
```

In your `upload.html:`

```
  <form action="{% url 'save_machine' %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="machine_name">
            <legend>Select Machine Name</legend>
            {% for machine in machines %}
            <option value="{{ machine.machine_name }}">
{{ machine.machine_name }}</option><!--Give indentation yourself I can't 
                                    because here doesn't have enough 
                                    space-->
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <select name="operation_no">
            <legend>Select Operation Number</legend>
            {% for machine in machines %}
            <option value="{{ machine.operation_no }}">
{{ machine.operation_no }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    
    <tr>
        <td>{{choiced_machine.machine_name}}</td>
        <td>{{choiced_machine.operation_no}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'machine_name'      I am getting this error

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I have edited the code in `upload.html`. Check out that

Comment: i seen that, you edited and i copied that and pasted it but showing above error

Comment: @ManojTolagekar if it doesn't work then use `request.POST.get('machine_name', '')` and `request.POST.get('operation_no','')` these two lines inside your `views.py`, instead of using `request.POST['machine_name']` and `request.POST['operation_no']`

Comment: It is not working again.

Comment: usermaster.models.Machine.DoesNotExist: Machine matching query does not exist.                          getting this error

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I have seen your code but I norice that you have not fully edited my code, so I am telling you to see my code again and edit. If you are stuck in **NOT NULL Constraints failed** error, I give you 100% solution, you can also see my profile that I mostly answered **NOT NULL** problem most of the times